Rails Importmap Error: "Module specifier does not start with '/', './', or '../'" on Some iPhones
I'm encountering an issue with my Rails app that uses Importmap. The app works perfectly in most environments, including desktop browsers and Android devices. However, some iPhone users are experiencing the following error:
TypeError: Module specifier does not start with "/", "./", or "../".
I've verified that the code works on other iPhones and on Android, but the error persists on certain iPhone models. This suggests a potential compatibility issue, but I can't pinpoint the exact cause.
importmap.rb
pin "application", preload: true
pin_all_from "app/javascript/admin", under: "admin"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/frontend", under: "frontend"

layout head
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>

<% if is_admin? %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'admin/index' %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag 'admin' %>
<% else %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'frontend/index' %>
  <%= javascript_import_module_tag 'frontend' %>
<% end %>

What I've Tried:

Ensured the module paths are correct and start with /, ./, or ../.
Tested the app in multiple browsers on different devices, confirming that the issue is isolated to some iPhone models.
Cleared browser cache and reset network settings on affected devices.

Any insights on why this might be happening, or suggestions on how to resolve it, would be greatly appreciated.

https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails/tree/v1.2.3#expected-errors-from-using-the-es-module-shim
